# How to repair a PDF file with black boxes / rectangles?

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file, and occasionally, there appear black filled boxes across the width of the page. The strange thing is, that when I mark the area and hit 'copy' and then paste it in a text editor, the text that's hidden inside the black boxes appear!

I tried two different PDF viewers (Adobe and SumatraPDF) and they both present the file with 
I also searched for online PDF repairers but they only handle corrupted PDF file which cannot be opened. I also thought about converting to PostScript and fiddle with the source code and recompile but I don't know anything about it.

So, how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: It's most likely not broken, but a computer illiterate tried to black out some parts of the document. This depends of course on what document it is, where you got it from, and what you get by selecting ad copying the text below the black boxes. They're just black rectangles over the text. Get a PDF editor to fix this.

Comment: @daniel Can you recommend one? Is there an editor that can automatically fix all of the boxes?

Comment: There will probably be no editor that can automatically fix this. It's an image (or form) overlaid over text. There are enough documents where this might make sense, e.g. with partial transparency. Googling produces [the Foxit PDF editor](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/phantomPDF/) that is able to edit existing documents AFAICT. I've heard good feedback about their free PDF viewer. You can use the search function on this site, I'm sure it was asked before how to edit PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Edit > Preferences > Accessibility** and remove the tick from "Replace document colors".

This is it.